# switching language method runtime in cakePHP

Tags: cakephp

I would like to change language in cakePHP runtime...

I tried this in appController

```
public function c(){

    Configure::write('Config.language', 'de');
    I18n::locale('de_DE');
    $this->Session->write('Config.language', 'de_DE');
    $this->Session->write('Config.language', 'de');

    $this->redirect($this->here);
}
```

none of the above changed my language...

As a default I have

```
'defaultLocale' => env('APP_DEFAULT_LOCALE', 'en_EN')
```

So I tried to call http://www.example.com/app/c and it doesnt work

Comment: Always state your cakephp version! Is it for 3.x? I just wrote [about I18n](https://github.com/dereuromark/cakephp-tools/blob/master/docs/I18n/I18n.md) yesterday.

Comment: Yes it is version 3.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
use Cake\I18n\I18n;

I18n::locale('de_DE');
```

This should actually change the localeas stated in the [cookbook](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/internationalization-and-localization.html) 
But i see in the ent of yourmethod you have a redirect. You realize that your method changes the langauge for the acual request?
 If you redirect then the default locale from app.php is set again.
 If you dynamically want to set the locale, you have to set in in a place which is called in every request, like in bootstrap.php or in the AppController beforeFilter method. There you could implement a logic which sets the locale according to e.g. url or such.

Comment: thats usefull information, thanks... but how I set it so it will remain